# pytest two level of parametrization with one parameter dependent on other one

Tags: python, pytest, dynamicparameters

I have to a test a scenario where one parameter is dependent on other. I tried using the pytest hook `pytest_generate_test` but i'm not sure how to pass a retrieve the value in hook which is parametrized in the test.

```
import pytest
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
apps = ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    common_services = ['dns', 'dhcp']
    service = apps[0]
    common_services.append(service)
    if "total_services" in metafunc.fixturenames:
       metafunc.parametrize("total_services", common_services)

@pytest.fixture()
def total_services(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.mark.parametrize("app", apps)
def test_example(app, total_services):
    logging.info(f"App: {app}, ServiceName: {total_services}")
```

Output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.7, pytest-8.0.2, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/test/tests
collected 9 items

test_example.py::test_example[dns-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 11%]
test_example.py::test_example[dns-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 22%]
test_example.py::test_example[dns-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 33%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 44%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 55%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 66%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: app1
PASSED                                                                   [ 77%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: app1
PASSED                                                                   [ 88%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: app1
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

============================== 9 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

Expected output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.7, pytest-8.0.2, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/test/tests
collected 9 items

test_example.py::test_example[dns-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 11%]
test_example.py::test_example[dns-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 22%]
test_example.py::test_example[dns-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: dns
PASSED                                                                   [ 33%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 44%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 55%]
test_example.py::test_example[dhcp-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: dhcp
PASSED                                                                   [ 66%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app1] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app1, ServiceName: app1
PASSED                                                                   [ 77%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app2] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app2, ServiceName: app2
PASSED                                                                   [ 88%]
test_example.py::test_example[app1-app3] 
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
INFO     root:test_example.py:21 App: app3, ServiceName: app3
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

============================== 9 passed in 0.01s ===============================
```

I know I have hard coded to get the first element of the list `service = apps[0]` i'm not sure how can we get the parameter passed in test can be retrieved in `pytest_generate_tests`

To keep explain it in simple way

```
from itertools import product


apps = ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']

def cartesian_product(app, common_servcies):

    return list(product(app, common_servcies))

for app in apps:
    common_services = ['dns', 'dhcp']
    common_services.append(app)
    print(cartesian_product([app], common_services))

Output: 
$ python3 test_example2.py
[('app1', 'dns'), ('app1', 'dhcp'), ('app1', 'app1')]
[('app2', 'dns'), ('app2', 'dhcp'), ('app2', 'app2')]
[('app3', 'dns'), ('app3', 'dhcp'), ('app3', 'app3')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed some point in your question and all you want is a slightly odd product that you have already created in your mock example, then you should IMHO just use it as a **helper function** to generate the parameters for the `parametrize` decorator:

```py
import logging
from itertools import product

import pytest


def app_service_product(apps, common_services):
    return list(product(apps, common_services)) + [[a, a] for a in apps]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "app, service",
    app_service_product(["app1", "app2", "app3"], ["dns", "dhcp"]),
)
def test_example(app, service):
    logging.info(f"App: {app}, ServiceName: {service}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost solved your own problem. Here is one way to do it:

```py
import itertools
import logging

import pytest

SERVICES_AND_APPS = []
for app in ["app1", "app2", "app3"]:
    services = ["dns", "dhcp"] + [app]
    SERVICES_AND_APPS.extend(itertools.product(services, [app]))


# BEGIN sort
def custom_key(service_and_app):
    """Ensure sort order of dns, dhcp, app1, app2, app3."""
    custom_order = {
        "dns": "a1",
        "dhcp": "a2",
    }
    service, app = service_and_app
    return custom_order.get(service, service), app


SERVICES_AND_APPS.sort(key=custom_key)
# END sort


@pytest.mark.parametrize("service,app", SERVICES_AND_APPS)
def test_example(service, app):
    logging.info("app=%r, service=%r", app, service)
```

Notes

- The code between `BEGIN sort` and `END sort` ensures the order. If you don't care about the order (in general, you should not), then you can delete that part, which makes the script simpler to understand and shorter.
- The `custom_order` translate `dns` to `a1`, `dhcp` to `a2`, which ensure the order you are looking for.